# In "Love," who is Junior's "Good Man," and what does that imply about her?

Tags: character-analysis, love, toni-morrison

Late in Toni Morrison's *Love*, Junior starts referring to her "Good Man":

> And her Good Man agreed. As she knew from the beginning, he liked to see her win.
>
> They recognized each other the very first night when he gazed at her from his portrait. But it was in dream they got acquainted. No fuss, no bother, no recriminations -- he lifted her up to his shoulders, where she rode through an orchard of green Granny apples. When she woke in a bright, cold room, the dream-warmth was better than the blanket.

The portrait, unquestionably, is of Bill Cosey. But the leap that Junior makes -- from tough-as-nails, look-out-for-number-one survivor, to imagining a dead man as her personal protector -- seems to me surprising, out of character, and pretty  arbitrary.

Why does Junior "adopt" Cosey and cast him into the role of her "Good Man"? What does this signify about her character? Are we meant to understand her as being insane, unstable -- or is this part of her character more thematic? What theme is being expressed here - and how does such an instant, intense, intimate *imaginary* connection to Cosey fit in with the rest of the book, thematically?